# C# Entity Framework MySQL register spacial data with SRID 4326

Tags: c#, mysql, query-optimization

So we have the following MySQL table:

```sql
CREATE TABLE CLUB(
    Id INT auto_increment PRIMARY KEY,
    ClubName VARCHAR(256),
    GeoLocation POINT SRID 4326
);
```

As you can see our table Club has a *GeoLocation* column of the [spacial datatype Point](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/gis-class-point.html).

Using the Point datatype in C# with the Entity Framework is possible by using [`NetTopologySuite.Geometries`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/spatial) and our data annotations in the `Club` class look like this:

```csharp
[Table("club")]
public class Club
{
    [Key]
    [NotNull]
    [Column("Id", TypeName = "INT")]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(256)]
    [Column("ClubName", TypeName = "VARCHAR(256)")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    
    [Column("GeoLocation", TypeName = "POINT")]
    public Point GeoLocation { get; set; }
}
```

Now we want to only get clubs in the vicinity of the user. Easy:

```csharp
...
if (isFilteredByDistance)
{
    // TODO: EF is doing a switch on the SRID. But SRID is always 4326
    Point userLocation = new Point(userLongitude, userLatitude)
    {
        SRID = 4326
    };
    filteredClubs = filteredClubs
        .Where(club =>
            club.GeoLocation.IsWithinDistance(userLocation, someRadius));
}
...
```

The above LINQ code is part of a larger query that will be executed **server side**. Here's the interesting part of the generated MySQL query resulting from it:

```sql
...
AND 
    (CASE
        WHEN ST_SRID(`c`.`GeoLocation`) = 4326 
        THEN 
            ST_Distance_Sphere(`c`.`GeoLocation`, @__userLocation_5)
        ELSE 
            ST_Distance(`c`.`GeoLocation`, @__userLocation_5)
    END <= @__8__locals1_filter_Radius_6)) 
AND
...
```

As you can see the Entity Framework generated a switch case, checking if the SRID *of the database column `GeoLocation` is 4326* (which it always will be).
Even though it's not really a big deal, because the code works we'd like to optimize the automatically generated queries as much as possible. Therefore:

**How do we make the Entity Framework aware of the fact that the `GeoLocation` column in table `club` is in fact using SRID 4326 so that it doesn't generate this unnecessary switch case in MySQL?**

I guess there are some data annotations for it? Or some Fluent API syntax? Any help would be greatly appreciated